# Filehandling, move_uploaded_file gives me no response

Tags: php

Got a script I've used several times, using `move_uploaded_file`. But what I can't figure out is why it do not respond in any way, no error reports, nothing.

- `<form>` using `method="post"`, `target="upload"` that is an `<iframe>`
- `action="file.php"` responds to `$_FILES`
- Correct enctype
- Filerights is set to 777
- Upload folder "uploads" exists

`print_r($_FILES['file'])` gives me:

```
Array
(
    [name] =&gt; 1392930853.png
    [type] =&gt; image/png
    [tmp_name] =&gt; /tmp/php0rZdBf
    [error] =&gt; 0
    [size] =&gt; 611
)
```

The code below illustrates my script, and what I've figured out is that the last line with `move_uploaded_file` is the cause of my problem as it do not respond at all. As I wrote above, no error, no nothing.

Pastebin to script: http://pastebin.com/49m9Siqi

Got a clue what could be the cause of this?

```
$destination_path = getcwd().'/uploads/';
//echo $destination_path;

//  File handling
$counted = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
$counted = $counted-1;

for ($i=0; $i<=$counted; $i++) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$i] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $md5file = rand() . rand() . md5($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) . rand() . rand();    
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $destination_path . $md5file . "." . basename($_FILES['file']['type'][$i]))) {  echo 'THIS WILL NOT BE ECHOED OUT ON THE PAGE'; }}}
```

Comment: The first step would be to break down your code into multiple statements, and and check each value one by one. As it's currently written, it'd be a nightmare to try and debug this.

Comment: On certain systems, 777 for folder permissions won't work, least on one of mine. Try 755, which is better actually and safer. So, that could be a contributing factor. You may even want to change `$destination_path = getcwd().'/uploads/';` to `$destination_path = 'uploads/';` if running your script from the root of your server. You may need to play around with it a bit, like `$destination_path = '../uploads/';` depending on how many sub-folders you're in.

Comment: Try it without an iframe, see if you get the same results.

Comment: Changed folder permissions to 755. Played around with `$destination_path` with no success.

Comment: I have to use the iframe, just did this on another project and using almost the same code on the same server.

Comment: I understand, yet I wanted you to just test it without the iframe. If it works, then you'll know that is the reason. It's worth trying. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: http://php.net/move_uploaded_file "If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, **a warning will be issued.**" Find the warning

Comment: *Facepalm* I handle the file as an array, but did not make an array in my form..

Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simple error in my form, as I handle my uploaded files like an array I need to create the array first.... Which I forgot to do in my form.

Wrong

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Correct

```
<input type="file" name="file[]">
```